# Converting a file's indentation from tabs to spaces

Tags: vim, sed, awk, indentation

What's the best way to convert a tab-indented file into a space-indented one?

I'd like to be able to specify a variable number of spaces per tab replacement.

In other words, in every line that begins with a consecutive sequence of tabs, I'd like replace each tab of the sequence with X spaces, where I get to set X.

I don't mind what tool is used, whether it is AWK, sed, or even Vim.

Anyone know what the best way to do this is?

Update/paraphrase/clarification:

#### In other words, here is the process that I need to run the file through:

### "on each line, replace every tab character that precedes the first non-tab character on that line with 3 spaces"

Comment: Try: `expand -it 3 < original-file > new-file`

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{s="";i=1;while(substr($0,i++,1)=="\t")s=s "   ";sub(/^\t*/,s)}1'
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution on Linux or many Unix systems is to use the [`expand`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expand) command.

If you use Vi or Vim to edit your files, you can add the following to your `.vimrc` file to ensure tabs are always expanded to spaces when editing files:

```
set expandtab
```

For more information on Vim and tabs, see [Converting Tabs To Spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces).

Answer (score 4):

From within Vim, you first need to set the `'tabstop'` setting to the desired number of spaces a Tab should represent, and instruct Vim to expand to spaces:

```
:setlocal tabstop=3 expandtab
```

Then, you can change *all* (not just indent) Tabs to spaces via

```
:%retab
```

Comment: You do not need to specify `%`:  the default is the whole file.  Also, you can set the new value of `'tabstop'` in the `:retab` line:  `:setl expandtab` and then `:retab 3`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace all tabs with sequences of N blank chars:

```
pr -e3 -t file
```

The above says "replace every tab with 3 space chars and do not add a header", e.g.:

```
$ printf 'a\tb\tc\n'
a       b       c

$ printf 'a\tb\tc\n' | pr -e3 -t
a  b  c

$ printf 'a\tb\tc\n' | pr -e12 -t
a           b           c
```

If you only want to replace the leading tabs, then you can use (all spaces in "file" are tabs):

```
$ cat file
a       b
        c       d
                e       f

$ awk -v nc=3 'match($0,/^\t+/){ $0=sprintf("%*s%s",nc*RLENGTH,"",substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)) }1' file
a       b
   c    d
      e f

$ awk -v nc=12 'match($0,/^\t+/){ $0=sprintf("%*s%s",nc*RLENGTH,"",substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)) }1' file
a       b
            c   d
                        e       f
```

So you can see the tabs as #s:

```
$ cat file | tr '\t' '#'
a#b
#c#d
##e#f
$
$ awk -v nc=3 'match($0,/^\t+/){ $0=sprintf("%*s%s",nc*RLENGTH,"",substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)) }1' file | tr '\t' '#'
a#b
   c#d
      e#f
```

Also, take a look at the `indent` command if your UNIX has it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps VI(M) search & replace?  Replacing tabs with spaces will break the column-alignment...

```
:%s/\t/        /g
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one `awk`.  It will replace tabs with space, if it is the same tabs as in the `nt` value is set to:

```
awk  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="\t") t++;if (t==nt) for (i=1;i<=t;i++) $i=" ";t=0}1' nt=2 FS="" OFS="" file
```

With this file:

```
cat file
no tab
        test 1 tab
                more 2 tab
                        even more 3 tab
```

and `nt=2`, you get:

```
no tab
        test 1 tab
  more 2 tab
                        even more 3 tab
```

replaced two tab in line two

It could have been some more complex, to only look for tab at start of line.

Some more readable:

```
awk  '
    {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if ($i=="\t")
            t++
    if (t==nt) 
        for (i=1;i<=t;i++) 
            $i=" "
    t=0
    }
    1
    ' nt=2 FS="" OFS="" file
```